# How do I map a Comparator<T> to a Comparator<U> using a Function<T, U>?

Tags: java, functional-programming, comparator

I have a *comparator* of type `Comparator<Integer>` and a *function* `Function<Pair<Integer,?>,Integer>` expressed as `Pair::left` (that returns an `Integer`).

I need to obtain a *comparator* of type `Comparator<Pair<Integer,?>>`.

If I wanted to simply map a *function* `Function<T,U>` to a *resulting function* `Function<T,V>` though a *function* `Function<U,V>` I could simply apply `andThen()` method like this:

```java
Function<Integer, String> toBinary = Integer::toBinaryString;
Function<Pair<Integer, ?>, Integer> left = Pair::left;

var pairToBinary = left.andThen(toBinary); // has type Function<Pair<Integer, ?>, String>
```

Is it possible to obtain `Comparator<Pair<Integer,?>>` in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you can use your function `pairToBinary` as an argument in [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) to obtain a comparator of type `Comparator<Pair<Integer,?>>`.

```
record Pair<L, R>(L left, R right) {}
    
Function<Integer, String> toBinary = Integer::toBinaryString;
Function<Pair<Integer, ?>, Integer> left = Pair::left;
var pairToBinary = left.andThen(toBinary); // has type Function<Pair<Integer, ?>, String>
        
Comparator<Pair<Integer, ?>> comparator = Comparator.comparing(pairToBinary);
```

Alternatively, you can use another flavor of [`comparing(keyExtractor,keyComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)), in this case you don't need to declare any of these functions:

```
Comparator<Pair<Integer, ?>> comparator1 =
    Comparator.comparing(Pair::left,                    // keyExtractor function
        Comparator.comparing(Integer::toBinaryString)); // keyComparator which is capable of comparing objects produced by keyExtractor
```

> I only have `Pair::left` and a `Comparator<Integer>`

If you have on your hands a *function* which produces `Integer` and `Comparator<Integer>`, that's precisely the use-case for `comparing(keyExtractor,keyComparator)`.

You need to provide a *function* (`Pair::left` or whatever) as the first argument and a *comparator*, which can compare objects produced by the *function*, as the second argument:

```
Comparator.comparing(Pair::left, myIntComparator)
```

Comment: This works if I have two functions, but that was just an example. I actually have one comparator and one function and want to compose them using something like `andThen` for functions, `map` for Streams (afaik), etc.

Comment: This still doesn't work for my purpose, as I don't intend to chain functions. I only have `Pair::left` and a `Comparator<Integer>` and want to get a `Comparator<Pair>`. Its `compare` method should first call `Pair::left` on the given pairs and then compare them using the provided `Comparator<Integer>`.

Comment: I found the solution, it is just to call `Comparator.comparing(Pair::left, cmp)` where cmp is the `Comparator<T>`. The reason this didn't work in the beginning was just a simple typo.

Comment: If you were to incorporate that into your answer, I could accept it as the correct one.

Comment: @leo848 That exactly the use case for `comparing()` which expects *keyExtractor* function and comparator for the key *keyComparator*. Updated the answer.